# Can I get some space back in inkscapes GUI?

Tags: inkscape

I installed inkscape 1.0 and found that I got extra icons

[image: screenshot]

Can I hide the ones I highlit?

Any other tips on how to free some space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on *View > Default*, to switch that icon bar to run along the top.